# Adobe CS 5.5 and the most recent version of Ubuntu

Tags: adobe

I am a long time Mac user who is sick and tired OS X slowly becoming Windows. Adobe CS 5.5 is the main reason I own a computer, these programs make my computer into a tool rather than a toy. I am looking into switching to Ubuntu, but need some reassurance that the most current version will be able to run Adobe CS 5.5 through the most recent version of Wine or other emulator. Please note, my copies for CS 5.5 are for Mac OS.

So, can I make the switch in the knowledge that I can use Adobe CS 5.5 on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

If you are a diehard Adobe CS user, and that's your primary/exclusive reason to use your computer, moving to Ubuntu will be VERY stressful. Can you get Adobe to more-or-less run on wine? Sure. But you will no doubt have glitches, bugs, and crashes to work through. All that In addition to learning a new OS and possibly working out some os-hardware issues.

I love Ubuntu and don't want you to dissuade you from coming over "to the dark side."  But you need to be in it for the right reasons. "OSX feels like Windows and I want a better way to run Adobe CS" isn't the typical use case.

Comment: Thank you for your honesty, this is the kind of answer I need in order to assess all of my options.